# Embedding Google+ Hangout App in web application

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-hangouts

Is there any way to embed a Google+ hangout app in a PHP-based website? Can I load the app inside an iframe without having to land on Google+ hangout page? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research I found out that we can not embed a Google+ Hangout in our application. We can only do that inside a Google+ hangout page. There's an [active issue tracker opened](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=28) on code.google.com where you can vote up and comment so that Google can release this feature in the coming API releases.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. Launching a Hangout Video Call from your own website is possible, but without special coordination with Google, it will open it in its own window/tab.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4 for further information about how to start a Hangout Video Call from your own website.

Comment: Actually, one can only launch a Google+ hangout from Google+ page itself (at least in the current API).

Comment: I stand by my statement, both in text and in the video. While you can't embed a hangout in your website, you can launch one from your website. To be clear - this does involve going to a Google URL, but you can still launch it from your website, specifying a hangout app to launch with it, and providing parameters to that app.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4 talks about how to start hangouts from your web page using the API.

Comment: Also. You can embed on air hangouts, I just don't know if you can automate it on-the-fly programatically.

Comment: Note that the video you pointed to is the same one I pointed to above. {: You can't really embed a HoA - you can embed a YouTube video stream that shows the HoA, but you can't embed the Hangout portion itself. There is an API call that will provide you with the YouTube video ID, which can be used to embed the video, and the rest is automatable depending on your server. (But that didn't sound like what the question was trying to ask.)

Comment: @Jake, yes I agree. What I wanted to convey with the word 'embed' is the ability to start a hangout app inside of my website. As in, I won't need to redirect to Google+ page in order to start a hangout app. And as I wrote in the answer to my original post, at the time of my research, there weren't any ways using which a hangout app could have been embedded in my website.